# Match a serialized value in a field

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Please I have a table with two fields `ID` and `Value`. The field `Value` contains a serialized array using php :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID |                        Value                                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | a:2:{s:1:"0";s:12:"dHJhbnNwb3J0";s:1:"2";s:16:"Y2VudHJlIHZpbGxl";}|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | a:1:{s:1:"0";s:16:"Y2VudHJlIHZpbGxl";}                            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  | a:2:{s:1:"0";s:12:"Y29tbWVyY2U=";s:1:"2";s:12:"dHJhbnNwb3J0";}    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my form, I have a field also named `Value` with checkbox, where the user could choose more than one choice, and data will be sent in an array named `value[]` :

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="dHJhbnNwb3J0" /> Value One
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="Y2VudHJlIHZpbGxl" /> Value Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="Y29tbWVyY2U" /> Value Three
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Look for" />
</form>
```

I want to select data where the field value exists in the serialized field, so I thought to use `REGEXP` in mysql and I've tried

```
$clause = '';
for($i = 0 ; $i < $c; ++$i)
    $clause .= " OR Value REGEXP '{$_POST['value'][$i]}';

// This is the query used :
$q = " SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE value = '{$_POST['value'][0]}' $clause  ";
```

But this doesn't match what I need.

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: just use `Value LIKE '%{$_POST['value'][$i]}%'`

Comment: Why do you use MySQL if you don't have *structured* data stored there?   Now you can't do what you want to and you think your approach is correct one when it isn't. An XY problem, please look it up.

Comment: @Akam, thank you I will use only LIKE, it seems to work perfectely !

Comment: @N.B. : Yes I agree, is my friend's siteweb and unfortunately it was realized by a web agency !

Comment: Using LIKE will be slow, plus if you are looking for a value of (say) 16 it will find records which happen to have a length of 16. It is possible to split up the serialised array using MySQL (I did it in a stored proc for a simple serialised array at work), but it is quite horrible to code and quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['value']) && is_array($_POST['value'])) {
    $re = '"(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $_POST['value'])) . ')"';
    $q = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE value REGEXP '$re'";
    // execute query, proceed results
}
```

Still you have wrong architecture, this is a wrong way to ask your database. You should reconsider the way you are storing values: serialized data is NOT meant to be used in a search criteria.